# Requests to azure table storage in different DC getting slower and slower

Tags: c#, performance, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-cloud-services

My cloud service writes data to two azure table storages in two separate data centers. When I test the service with larger load the table storage in the same data center as the service keeps it's latency (around 10ms), but the operations to the other data center (I think it's East US 2 from West Europe) are getting slower and slower until they take around 5 seconds.

I checked the storage monitoring and there are no throttling errors, so I am pretty sure I am not breaking the max number of requests. I can't see any network errors or anything like that for the storage, so I guess the delay must be result of something else.

My cloud service is not cpu intensive. I tried to set no retry policy, but there are no errors, those table operations are successful, they just take a lot of time. Each request has a different partition key. The cloud service is Asp.NET Web Api running as a worker role, each table operation is run async.

What can be the issue here? Is Azure throttling requests between datacenters?

Comment: First place to start is the storage analytics logs.  Get analytics logs for both storage accounts and see if the difference is in server latency or end to end latency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the http connection limit is set to two. Increasing this limit means more than two requests will be processed at the same time, which will increase the performance. http://tk.azurewebsites.net/2012/12/10/greatly-increase-the-performance-of-azure-storage-cloudblobclient/

Answer (score 1):

Requests do not get throttled so long as your application is within the storage performance and scalability target (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/).
Please see troubleshooting guidance section under Monitor, diagnose, and troubleshoot Microsoft Azure Storage MSDN article (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting/#troubleshooting-guidance) to understand the source of high latency.